# Selenium Webdriver loop control, infinite loop Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I have the following for loop but for some reason im having trouble getting into the if statements inside the loop. Im using a counter to control the loop but for some reason the counter never starts at zero and seems to start at random numbers.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is wrong with my code.

```
public static void chk_DateAreInRange() throws Exception{
    try
    {
        Date startDate = new Date();
        Date endDate = new Date();
        int abc = 0;
        elementString = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Content_gvList"));
        final List<WebElement> dates = elementString.findElements(By.xpath(".//td[1]"));
        do
        {

            for (WebElement date : dates)
            {
                System.out.println("inside dates for" +abc);
                if(abc == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("inside if x=0");
                    String[] parsedString = date.getText().toString().split("\\-");// splits the webelement into a string from the - icon
                    Date ddd = formatter.parse(parsedString[0]);//gets the date we need from string - 12 Nov 2014
                    String startdateString = formatter.format(ddd);
                    startDate = formatter.parse(startdateString); //  convert the string back into a date

                }
                if(abc == 99)
                {
                    System.out.println("inside if x=99");
                    String[] parsedString = date.getText().toString().split("\\-");// splits the webelement into a string from the - icon
                    Date ddd = formatter.parse(parsedString[0]);//gets the date we need from string - 12 Nov 2014
                    String startdateString = formatter.format(ddd);
                    endDate = formatter.parse(startdateString); //  convert the string back into a date
                }
                abc++;
            }

        }while(abc != 99);
        if(getFromDateFull().before(startDate) || getToDateFull().after(endDate)){System.out.println("Date is not in range");}
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.error("TOP dropdown is not found on the PLP View Schedule Page");
        throw(e);
        }
    }
```

Console Output.

```
inside dates for349625
inside dates for349626
inside dates for349627
inside dates for349628
inside dates for349629
inside dates for349630
inside dates for349631
inside dates for349632
inside dates for349633
inside dates for349634
inside dates for349635
inside dates for349636
inside dates for349637
inside dates for349638
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Selenium?

Comment: not much, just thought id add it in :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your test as:

```
}while(abc < 99);
```

Answer (score 1):

in fact you begin at 0 but in your second loop you do abc++ so if you have `List<WebElement> dates`  with more than 99 elements, when inside loop finish your abc is greater than 99... so you condition

```
while(abc != 99);
```

never stop your traitment...

precision : you can have 10 elements in `List<WebElement> dates` but as you can see

- the second loop begin and abc = 10 then abc != 99 so continue
- next loop abc = 20, abc != 99 so continue
- and after 10 loop abc = 100 and abc != 99 so continue again and again...

your code only work if `List<WebElement> dates` contains 1 element, 3 elements, or 11 elements ;)

Comment: you would still see *"inside if x=0"* but most likely the output is too fast to see this in the console.